# Problema con speech recognition

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial

buen día. Soy un programador novato y tengo problemas on el siguiente codigo. A la hora de ejecutarlo no retorna nada, en teoria debería de hacer el print y reconocer lo que entra en el microfono. Si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme, gracias.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Escuchando. . .")
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        rec = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(rec)
except:
   pass
```

Comment: El try-except podría estar capturando un error e ignorandolo. Que pasa si lo quitas?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: que tal, revise tu código y funciona a la perfección, como estas usando el micrófono por default, revisa que no lo estés utilizando con otra app de audio, ya sea discord teams ..etc, tienes que cerrarlas ya que a veces genera conflicto, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la inicialización del listener `listener = sr.Recognizer()` dentro del bucle, después del `print("Escuchando. . .")`.

El código quedaría así:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

try:
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Escuchando. . .")
        listener = sr.Recognizer()
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        rec = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(rec)
except:
   pass
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.